# Is it safe to change the iterator dynamically in python?

Tags: python, iteration

With python, I need to add members in a list dynamically when the list is iterated over:

```
i = [1,2,3,4,5]

for a in i:
    if a == 1:
        i.append(100)
    print a
```

Is it guaranteed to work correctly?

Comment: `list.append` is okay, but [`list.remove` is not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That is perhaps a bit of an oversimplification.

Comment: I'd recommend iterating over a slice `[:]`for list manipulation, but that's just for safety, yours should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing the sequence, not the iterator. The `for` loop calls `iter()` on the object you are looping over, creating a loop iterator. For a `list` object, the list iterator created keeps a reference to the original list and an internal index, and every time the `for` loop asks for the next item (calls `next()` on the iterator), the item at the current index is returned and the index is incremented.

In *this case* it is safe, as the loop iterator object will happily continue over the extra items. As long as you don't add items to `i` indefinitely, the loop will complete.

If you were to *remove* items from `i`, however, the loop iterator would not see those changes and you would get 'surprising' results:

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for a in i:
   if a == 1:
       del i[0]
   print a
```

prints:

```
1
3
4
5
```

because the loop iterator yields `i[1]` on the next iteration, which is now `3`, not `2`.

Similar problems would occur if you were to *insert* items before the current iteration index.

You can create the iterator yourself, and experiment manually to see what happens:

```
>>> i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> i_iter = iter(i)  # index starts at 0
>>> next(i_iter)      # now the index is 1
1
>>> del i[0]
>>> i
[2, 3, 4, 5]          # item at index 1 is 3
>>> next(i_iter)      # returns 3, next index is 2
3
>>> i.insert(0, 1)
>>> i
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       # item at index 2 is 3
>>> next(i_iter)      # returns 3, next index is 3
3
```

Comment: Though you need to be very careful if doing this that you don't add something to the list that triggers the condition that adds something to the list, or you could end up with an infinite loop.