# Removing element messes up the index

Tags: python, list

I have a simple question about lists

Suppose that I want to delete all 'a's from a list:

```
list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
for element in list:
    if element == 'a':
        list.remove('a')

print list
```

==> result:

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
```

I know this is happening because, after I remove the first 'a', the list index gets

incremented while all the elements get pushed left by 1.

In other languages, I guess one way to solve this is to iterate backwards from the end of the list..

However, iterating through reversed(list) returns the same error.

Is there a pythonic way to solve this problem??

Thanks

Comment: Dup: [Loop “Forgets” to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)

Comment: Reverse iteration isn't helping because you're using `remove`, which loops over the list from the front and removes the first occurence it finds. Don't use `remove` unless you really have no better option.

Comment: Please, don't use a `list` name as varible.

Answer (score 4):

One of the more Pythonic ways:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x != 'a', ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'])
['b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: I am curious.  What makes this pythonic?  I expect, that your way is faster, but one miss placed character and debugging this would drive me to drink.  I am fairly new to python and am genuinely curious.

Comment: I suppose because it uses the method defined for this exact purpose: `Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.`

Answer (score 3):

You should never modify a list while iterating over it.

A better approach would be to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to exclude an item:

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != 'a']
```

*Note: Don't use `list` as a variable name in Python - it masks the built-in `list` type.*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, when you remove an item from a list while iterating over it, the list index gets *out of sync*.  What both the other existing answers are hinting at is that you need to create a new list and copy over only the items you want.

For example:

```
existing_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

new_list = []

for element in existing_list:
    if element != 'a':
        new_list.append(element)

existing_list = new_list
print existing_list
```

outputs:  `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`