# How can I remove a certain element from an array?

Tags: python

I have a Python array.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to remove `N` with a certain condition from the `arr` and store it again in the `arr`.

The condition: the remainder divided by 2 is 0 (it can be any other condition depending on the context)

For example, when removing `N` the remainder divided by 2 is 0, the result should be `[1, 3, 5]`. I want to use lambda for this but I don't know how.

Using JavaScript I can do this like this.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510140/best-way-to-remove-elements-from-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value)

Comment: if you show me waht it looks like in javascript maybe I can help you more because I am an avid python and javascript programer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to remove elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510140/best-way-to-remove-elements-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lop through the array and remove any values with remainders you will get the desired affect:

**This is how:**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
#Loops through the array and removes values with a remaider

arr = [N for N in arr if N%2 != 0] 
print(arr)
```

**Output:**
`[1 , 3 ,5]`

Answer (score 1):

As you want a generic solution where you can change the formula, the normal Pythonic approach to this would be use a conditional logic in a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#how-to-supercharge-your-comprehensions), for example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr = [x for x in arr if x%2 != 0]
```

This recreates the list only with elements that match your criterion (so, as you want to remove elements where `x%2 == 0`, this flips in the list comprehension to only add items to the list where `x%2 != 0`.

As you did ask for a method that uses a lambda function, so you could (if you really wanted to, I can't say I recommend it) use:

```
func = lambda x : [x for x in arr if x%2 != 0]
arr = func(arr)
```

or

```
func2 =  lambda x : x%2 != 0
arr = [x for x in arr if func2(x)]
```