# How to check float string?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which consists irregular words and `float` numbers, I'd like to delete all these `float` numbers from the list, but first I need to find a way to detect them. I know `str.isdigit()` can discriminate numbers, but it can't work for `float` numbers. How to do it?

My code is like this:

```
my_list = ['fun','3.25','4.222','cool','82.356','go','foo','255.224']
for i in my_list:
    if i.isdigit() == True:
        my_list.pop(i)
# Can't work, i.isdigit returns False
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use exception handling and a list comprehension. [Don't modify the list while iterating over it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)

```
>>> def is_float(x):
...     try:
...         float(x)
...         return True
...     except ValueError:
...         return False

>>> lis = ['fun','3.25','4.222','cool','82.356','go','foo','255.224']
>>> [x for x in lis if not is_float(x)]
['fun', 'cool', 'go', 'foo']
```

To modify the same list object use slice assignment:

```
>>> lis[:] = [x for x in lis if not is_float(x)]
>>> lis
['fun', 'cool', 'go', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy way:

```
new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    try:
        float(item)
    except ValueError:
        new_list.append(item)
```

Using *regular expressions*:

```
import re
expr = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d*)')

new_list = [item for item in my_list if not expr.match(item)]
```

A point about using `list.pop()`:

> When you use `list.pop()` to alter an existing list, you are shortening the length of the list, which means altering the indices of the list. This will lead to unexpected results if you are simultaneously iterating over the list. Also, `pop()` takes the *index* as an argument, not the element. You are iterating over the *element* in `my_list`. It is better to create a new list as I have done above.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand OP the function should only remove floats. If integers should stay - consider this solution:

```
def is_float(x):
    try:
        return int(float(x)) < float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False

my_list = ['fun', '3.25', 'cool', '82.356', 'go', 'foo', '255.224']
list_int = ['fun', '3.25', 'cool', '82.356', 'go', 'foo', '255.224', '42']

print [item for item in my_list if not is_float(item)]
print [item for item in list_int if not is_float(item)]
```

**Output**

```
['fun', 'cool', 'go', 'foo']
['fun', 'cool', 'go', 'foo', '42']
```

Comment: correct ints are  not float, I like  `is_float()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

A dead simple list comprehension, adding only slightly to `isdigit`:

```
my_list = [s for s in my_list if not all(c.isdigit() or c == "." for c in s)]
```

This will remove string representations of both `int` and `float` values (i.e. any string `s` where all characters `c` are numbers or a full stop).

Comment: + for yet another technique, only the problem is it doesn't validates float as if `s = '123.45.66.'`..

Comment: True, but that may not be a problem for the OPs data

Comment: Yes, correct. thats why I like answer, as OP *don't* want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would do the trick - this code searches each string for the format of a float (including floats starting with or ending with a decimal point), and if the string is not a float, adds it to the new list.

```
import re    
my_list = ['fun','3.25','4.222','cool','82.356','go','foo','255.224']
new_list = []
for pos, st in enumerate(my_list):
    if not re.search('[0-9]*?[.][0-9]*', st):
        new_list.append(st)
print new_list
```

Creating a new list avoids working on the same list you are iterating on.

Ewans answer is cleaner and quicker, I think.

Comment: Your regular expression may run into problems. Probably better to restrict the match to digits only.