# Python: at_least_n (iterating over lists)

Tags: python, list, iteration

Ben Bitdiddle is required to implement a function `at_least_n` which
takes in a list of integers and an integer n, and returns the original
list with all the integers smaller than n removed.

Example:

```
>>> lst = list(range(10))
>>> lst2 = at_least_n(lst, 5)
>>> lst2
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst is lst2
True
```

Define a code `at_least_n`.

HELP??? I've been staring at this and trying almost everything but I can't get an answer :/

Comment: And you have not tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 3):

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is our friend here:

```
>>> lst = list(range(10))
>>> [x for x in lst if x >= 5]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I don't write the full function for you. You have to be able to do it by yourself (It's a function of one line...).

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down, you need three things:

- a function
- a loop inside that function which loops through all the items in the list (which is provided by an argument)
- inside the loop: check if the number is larger or equal to the second argument of the function.

I guess it would be easier to just give you the code, but that is not really helpful. The words here should help you figuring it out yourself.

Comment: For OP: If you're following this approach and you're using `list.remove` during the iteration, then please have a look at this thread first: [Loop “Forgets” to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)