# For loop only process the first number of the list

Tags: python

```
number3=[30, 32, 34, 36, 50, 52, 54, 90, 300, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 320, 322, 323, 324, 325, 340, 342, 343, 360, 500, 502, 503, 504, 505, 520, 522, 523, 540, 900]
for i in (number3):
    m=str(i)
    n=len(m)
    if n == 2:
        number3.remove(i)
    else:
        pass
```

I don't know why, but the interpreter only processes the first number. I want it go through the whole list and remove the number which have 2 digits

Comment: the proper syntax of the for loop would be: `for i in number3:`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to modify a list while iterating over it. It's much easier to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do this:

```
number3 = [n for n in number3 if len(str(n)) != 2]
```