# Comparing two lists and filtering out duplicates

Tags: python, list, compare

Maybe this is just from mental exhaustion, but I can not for the life of me figure this out, even though i used the same principle on another program I created..

I have two lists:

```
compare_list = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,7,5,8,9,9]

master_list = [0,1,2,3,4,8,9]
```

As you can see both lists contain some numbers that are the same, and in compare_list you have values that have duplicates..

What I want completed is to compare both lists, and delete from the compare_list if it finds it in the master_list.

This is the code i have so far:

```
for x in compare_list:
    for y in master_list:
        if x == y:
            compare_list.remove(x)
```

The result is that i do have some items being deleted from compare_list, but i still have some duplicates left..

output:

```
  print(compare_list)

 [1,3,7,5,9]
```

how do i get it right where it deletes all instances of duplicates from master_list. so that compare_list just contains numbers that aren't found in master_list?

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify `compare_list` while you are iterating over it

Comment: Related: [Loop “Forgets” to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)

Comment: Have you looked into using Python's sets?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your expected output. Looks like maybe you want the intersection of the two lists?

Comment: Are duplicates allowed in the `master_list` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a straight-forward use case for `filter`

```
>>> compare_list = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,7,5,8,9,9]
>>> master_list = [0,1,2,3,4,8,9]
>>> filter(lambda i: i not in master_list, compare_list)
[7, 5]
```

Comment: OP: "What I want completed is to compare both lists, and delete from the compare_list if it finds it in the master_list."

Comment: That is what I did. To "delete it from compare_list" you just assign the return value of `filter` back to `compare_list`

Answer (score 0):

```
compare_list = [x for x in compare_list if x not in master_list]
```

If `master_list` has more than a few items, it will be more efficient to use a `set`

```
master_set = set(master_list)
compare_list = [x for x in compare_list if x not in master_set]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the python official documentation *list.remove* 
"Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item."

So if you have duplicates in your *compare_list* you won't remove them.

If you already have a list and you need to remove duplicates from it I think that you need to convert your list in a set:

```
compare_list = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]
my_set = set(compare_list)
```

If you need to filter the *compare_list* removing some specific elements you can do this step after you've transformed the list into a set using the [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)'s method *remove*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

compare_list = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,7,5,8,9,9]
master_list = [0,1,2,3,4,8,9]

comp_set = collections.Counter(compare_list)
master_set = collections.Counter(master_list)

print comp_set-master_set
```

Producing:

```
Counter({1: 1, 3: 1, 9: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1})
```

---

Please beware that [`substract()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract) might lead to `0` or negative counts. So to use effectively your result you probably have to add an extra pass:

```
print [k for k,v in (comp_set-master_set).items() if v > 0]
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Producing:

```
[1, 3, 9, 5, 7]
```