# python: removing multiple item in list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove every item in b that's in a, the out would be [7,8,9,0], how can I do it, this doesn't seem to work

```
In [21]:
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3,5,5,5,7,8,9,0]
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        print i
        b.remove(i)
print b
```

#

```
Out[21]:
1
3
5
[2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Reason: [Loop “Forgets” to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items)

Comment: Swapping the order of iteration to list 'a' and then list 'b and also replacing your inner "if" with "while" will also work, but I like the solution by @shx2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension and the `in` operator.

```
b = [ elem for elem in b if elem not in a ]
```

For speed, you can first change `a` into a set, to make lookup faster:

```
a = set(a)
```

EDIT: as pointed out by @Ignacio, this does not modify the original list inplace, but creates a new list and assigns it to `b`. If you must change the original list, you can assign to `b[:]` (read: replace all elements in `b` with the elements in RHS), instead of `b`, like:

```
b[:] = [ elem for ... ]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually remove them from `b`, it creates a new list containing those items not in `a`.

Comment: @kender, yes, python is :)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the items from list 'b' that are already in list 'a'

```
[b.remove(item) for item in a if item in b]
```

Updated as per @shx2:

```
 for item in a:
     while item in b:
         b.remove(item)
```

Also, you could make it faster by making list 'a' a set

```
 for item in set(a):
     while item in b:
         b.remove(item)
```

Comment: don't use a list comprehension when what you need is a loop... Also, this won't remove all occurences of duplicate items.