# Remove odd-indexed elements from list in Python

Tags: python, list, element

I'm trying to remove the odd-indexed elements from my list (where zero is considered even) but removing them this way won't work because it throws off the index values.

```
lst = ['712490959', '2', '623726061', '2', '552157404', '2', '1285252944', '2', '1130181076', '2', '552157404', '3', '545600725', '0']


def remove_odd_elements(lst):
    i=0
    for element in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            lst.remove(element)
        i = i + 1
```

How can I iterate over my list and cleanly remove those odd-indexed elements?

Comment: Fun fact: to remove all even (positioned) elements you can do: `for x in lst: lst.remove(x)`. To remove all odds do: `iter_lst = iter(lst); next(iter_lst); for x in iter_lst: lst.remove(x)`. So, basically, removing the `if` solves the problem... I hope I don't have to say to never actually use this stuff in real code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can delete all odd items in one go using a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
del lst[1::2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['712490959', '2', '623726061', '2', '552157404', '2', '1285252944', '2', '1130181076', '2', '552157404', '3', '545600725', '0']
>>> del lst[1::2]
>>> lst
['712490959', '623726061', '552157404', '1285252944', '1130181076', '552157404', '545600725']
```

You cannot delete elements from a list while you iterate over it, because the list iterator doesn't adjust as you delete items. See [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items) what happens when you try.

An alternative would be to build a new list object to replace the old, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) providing the indices:

```
lst = [v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if i % 2 == 0]
```

This *keeps* the even elements, rather than remove the odd elements.

Comment: Ohhh so the notation basically means [start:end:stride]

Comment: Note to readers: the solution for deleting even items is even simpler: `del lst[::2]`

Comment: You can't remove elements from a list while iterating over it forwards and carelessly :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to eliminate odd items and keep the even ones , you can use a filter as follows :

```
>>>filtered_lst=list(filter(lambda x : x % 2 ==0 , lst))
```

this approach has the overhead of creating a new list.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what is happening because modification during iteration is a common problem if it's not done right

Here is a simple list

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

When `idx = 1`, you drop element `1`:

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5
   ^
```

Then you increment `idx` two more times before dropping another element:

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5
         ^
```

So now you have

```
0, 2, 3, 5
```

Luckily (or unluckily), a list iterator allows you to modify the underlying data without breaking.

There are a couple of ways to fix this. The first one is to iterate backwards. Also, don't iterate over a collection when you modify it, keep the index external. You can still use a `for` loop though:

```
for idx in range(len(elements) - 1, -1, -1):
    if idx % 2:
        del elements[idx]
```

Don't forget to use `del` to drop elements by index instead of value.

If you're absolutely sure that the input has an even size, you can remove the conditional easily:

```
for idx in range(len(elements) - 1, -1, -2):
    del elements[idx]
```

For an arbitrary number of elements, it's only slightly more complicated to avoid the last potentially even element:

```
for idx in range(len(elements) // 2 * 2 - 1, -1, -2):
    del elements[idx]
```

In python, there are short-hand indices you can use to drop the elements directly. To do it in-place:

```
del elements[1::2]
```

Or the more commonly suggested option of making a copy:

```
elements = elements[::2]
```