# To keep removing odd indices element while list has more than 1 element

Tags: arrays, list

I have a list li = [1,2,3,4], I need to remove odd index from list each time, after removing odd index from a list I will get 2,4 then after again I need to remove odd element and I will get 4, which should be my output.

I tried solving this in Python:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = []
for i in range (len(li)):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        continue
    arr.append(li[i])
for i in range (len(arr)):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        continue
    print (arr[i])
```

But for same array i.e., li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15], i will get [4,8,12] and again removing odd indices from arr = [4,8,12].
I will get output 8 by removing odd index element.
How can I do with more optimal solution?

Comment: I don't understand... if you remove odd indices 2 times, then from `li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` you should get `[4, 8, 12]`.

Comment: I think the question will be to keep removing odd indices while arr has more than 1 element.

Comment: Yes, exactly keep removing odd indices while arr has more than 1 element and if I remove odd indices two times, then from li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] I should get [4,8,12] then again I have to remove odd indices from [4,8,12], so that my output will be 8 in this case, so how can I do without using any inbuilt function or without using list slicing method in recursion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883769/remove-odd-indexed-elements-from-list-in-python use this plus a recursive function that exits when 1 element is left

Comment: if you don't want to use list slicing and recursion then you need a while loop to check if your array has one element and then one method to loop and remove elements that gets called in the while loop

Comment: Why would you do this at all?   The element that will remain is the one with index that is the highest power of 2.  Repeatedly modifying the list seems pointless.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  lol it does seem pointless

Answer (score 0):

based on this answer:
[Remove odd-indexed elements from list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883769/remove-odd-indexed-elements-from-list-in-python)

```
def removeOddIndexesTilOneElement(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x

    del x[1::2]
    return removeOddIndexesTilOneElement(x)

li = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(removeOddIndexesTilOneElement(li))
```

Note that in your example with 1,2,3,4 my function will actually delete 2 and 4 because their indexes are 1 and 3. The index starts with 0. You might have to tweak this to remove even indexes if you want to get a result of 4. You could change one line to: del x[0::2] to get rid of even indexes.

No recursion, no slice trick method:

```
def removeOddIndex(x):
    ret = []
    for i in range (len(x)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            ret.append(x[i])
    return ret        
        

li = [1,2,3,4]

while len(li) > 1:
    li = removeOddIndex(li)

print(li)
```