# "list index out of range" - Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I was trying to write a piece of program that will remove any repeating items in the list, but I get a `list index out of range`

Here's the code:

```
a_list = [1, 4, 3, 2, 3]

def repeating(any_list):
    list_item, comparable = any_list, any_list
    for x in any_list:
        list_item[x]
        comparable[x]
        if list_item == comparable:
            any_list.remove(x)

    print(any_list)

repeating(a_list)
```

So my question is, what's wrong?

Comment: What do you think `x` is in this case? Also, assigning a list to another name doesn't create a copy, just adds another reference to that list.

Comment: Your equality test will always be true, and thus items will be removed such that the indices will no longer be valid.

Comment: you don't even know for loop in python... grab a text book first.

Comment: As such, `list_item == comparable` is **always true**.

Comment: Don't really get the point of the this in general.

Comment: Yeah, but if remove the `list_item` and `comparable` I'll have a error as such variables are not defined soooo...

Comment: So can I do something like `length = len(any_list)` and on the next line `for x in range(length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not do what you think it does.

First you are creating additional references to the same list here:

```
list_item, comparable = any_list, any_list
```

`list_item` and `comparable` are just additional names to access the same list object.

You then loop over the values *contained* in `any_list`:

```
for x in any_list:
```

This assigns first `1`, then `4`, then `3`, then `2`, then `3` again to `x`.

Next, use those values as indexes into the other two references to the list, but ignore the result of those expressions:

```
list_item[x]
comparable[x]
```

This doesn't do anything, other than test if those indexes exist.

The following line then is **always true**:

```
if list_item == comparable:
```

because the two variables reference the same list object.

Because that is always true, the following line is always executed:

```
any_list.remove(x)
```

This removes the first `x` from the list, making the list *shorter*, while still iterating. This causes the `for` loop to *skip* items as it'll move the pointer to the next element. See [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items) for why that is.

All in all, you end up with 4, then 3 items in the list, so `list_item[3]` then fails and throws the exception.

The *proper* way to remove duplicates is to use a [`set` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
def repeating(any_list):
    return list(set(any_list))
```

because a `set` can only hold unique items. It'll alter the order however. If the order is important, you can use a [`collections.OrderedDict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
def repeating(any_list):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(any_list))
```

Like a `set`, a dictionary can only hold unique keys, but an `OrderedDict` actually also keeps track of the order of insertion; the `dict.fromkeys()` method gives each element in `any_list` a value of `None` unless the element was already there. Turning that back in to a list gives you the unique elements in a first-come, first serve order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a_list = [1, 4, 3, 2, 3]
>>> list(set(a_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a_list))
[1, 4, 3, 2]
```

See [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) for more options still.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your issue is to convert the list to a set and then, back to a list...

```
def repeating(any_list):
    print list(set(any_list))
```

You're probably having an issue, because you're modifying the list (removing), while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates in a list but don't care about the elements formatting then you can

```
def removeDuplicate(numlist):
    return list(set(numlist))
```

If you want to preserve the order then

```
def removeDuplicate(numlist):
    return sorted(list(set(numlist)), key=numlist.index)
```