# for-loop ignores some elements of list, when in combination with if-statement

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I would like to iterate over the elements of a list, and delete the wrong ones. First, lets check all elements:

```
tikzFiles=['keepme.tikz','inputs.tex','bla1.bat','bla2.tex','bla3.py']

for sFile in tikzFiles:
    print(sFile)
    print(sFile.endswith('.tikz'))
```

This leads to the expected result:

```
keepme.tikz
True
inputs.tex
False
bla1.bat
False
bla2.tex
False
bla3.py
False
```

Two more lines, however,

```
for sFile in tikzFiles:
    print(sFile)
    print(sFile.endswith('.tikz'))
    if not sFile.endswith('.tikz'):
        tikzFiles.remove(sFile)
```

let the for-loop ignore the elements 'bla1.bat' and 'bla3.py':

```
keepme.tikz
True
inputs.tex
False
bla2.tex
False
```

Comment: You're modifying the list whilst looping so the position that the iterator is using is no longer referencing the original list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension to create a new list with only the elements you want, like this

```
>>> tikzFiles = ['keepme.tikz', 'inputs.tex', 'bla1.bat', 'bla2.tex', 'bla3.py']
>>> [file for file in tikzFiles if file.endswith('.tikz')]
['keepme.tikz']
```

**Note:** More often, removing an element from a collection while you iterate it, is a bad idea. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17299676/1903116) to know more about what is actually going on at runtime.

Comment: Thanks,Thats it. I just want to mention that I wanted the elements that end with '.tikz', so I had to remove the 'not' from our answer.

Comment: @bbk Sorry, I updated the answer :-)