# How can I remove a dict item from a tuple of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple of dicts in form:

```
mylist = ({'a': 'a0',  't': 't0'}, {'a': 'a1',  't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2',  't': 't2'}, ...)
```

How can I remove a dict in the for loop? I tried the following but at the end `doc` is still in the tuple:

```
for doc in mylist:
    if doc['a']=="a0":
        del doc
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove an item from a list as you are iterating through that list?  That's usually a very bad idea.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you will have to create a new tuple that doesn't include the relevant items.

Comment: Your code is basically doing `doc = mylist[0]; del doc`..., that's not going to affect the container in any way, you're simply removing the reference `doc` within the loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter Actually they are not removing the item at all.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: But that is what the code is *meant* to do, however unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't use the name `list`, you will shadow the built in list.

Tuples are immutable, so you have to build a new tuple.

```
>>> t = ({'a': 'a0',  't': 't0'}, {'a': 'a1',  't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2',  't': 't2'})
>>> tuple(d for d in t if d['a'] != 'a0')
({'a': 'a1', 't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2', 't': 't2'})
```

This assumes all your dictionaries actually have the key `'a'`. If that does not have to be the case, feel free to add some error checking code or use the `get` method of the dictionary with a fallback value in the generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

To start with; you have defined a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), not  a [List](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#list). The primary difference between the two is that Tuples are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This means if you want to modify your collection, you will need to use a List:

```
my_list = [{'a': 'a0',  't': 't0'}, {'a': 'a1',  't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2',  't': 't2'}]
```

*Note the use of square brackets, rather than round.*

With that knowledge, you can either choose to:

Build another Tuple, omitting the values you wish to remove:

```
my_tuple = ({'a': 'a0',  't': 't0'}, {'a': 'a1',  't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2',  't': 't2'})
my_new_tuple = tuple(item for item in my_tuple if item['a'] != 'a0')
```

Or, use a List, and remove the values you don't want:

```
my_list = [{'a': 'a0',  't': 't0'}, {'a': 'a1',  't': 't1'}, {'a': 'a2',  't': 't2'}]  
for item in my_list:
    if item['a'] == 'a0':
        my_list.remove(item)
```

Comment: @MSeifert You're right, my mistake! I've corrected it now.

Comment: @timgeb You're right; i'll add another example without the nested loops.

Comment: [`list.remove`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299581/loop-forgets-to-remove-some-items) is a bad suggestion.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Apparently so, it does have a relatively high level of computational complexity, but it serves as a relatively straight-forward example to checking a list. How would you do it differently?